# Weight and dimensions of Hive game pieces?

Tags: hive

What are the exact dimensions and weight of the bug pieces used in the game Hive?

What are they made of?

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: I was thinking about doing home-made version of the game and I wanted it (the dimensions) to be as close to the original as possible. As for the weight and material, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It varies by edition. There are at least 4 versions of the game.

Version 1 was stickered wooden pieces; I do not know the size, but I suspect them to be rather close to the Bakelite. At least two different sticker sets were used by Gen42 games.

Version 2 was bakelite pieces, hexagons 37mm face to face, and 12mm thick.

Version 3, "Hive Pocket" is also bakelite pieces, hexagons 24mm face to face, and 9.5mm thick.

Version 4, "Hive Carbon" is the same size pieces as the second version, but is black and white markings and tiles.

I lack a scale accurate enough to measure the mass.

Boardgamegeek.com has, on the hive entry, a table:

```
Item                         Hive    Hive Pocket
Tile Width Flat to Flat      38 mm   25 mm
Tile Height                  12 mm   10 mm
Weight of 26 tiles           600 g   200 g
```

[On one of the images](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/1216544/gen-four-two), it shows 38x12mm and 25x10mm for the bakelite

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to 3D print some tiles to go with my hive set so determined the answer to these questions for myself. From @aramis's answer, I deduce I have the "Hive Carbon" set.

My fairly precise scales and callipers suggest:

- Mass: 21.8g
- Height: 12.4mm
- Distance between parallel hexagon edges: 37.9mm

Printing my own part to these dimensions with 3mm fillets and 100% infill using PLA gave a mass of 17.3g. It's different enough to notice if you focus on it, but not so bad as to be terribly distracting. The bigger issue is surface finish, and I experimented with sanding from 240 to 2000 grit using wet/dry paper and a little water.

The original bakelite pieces are lovely. As fun as it's been to make my own expansion pieces, if I find I like playing with them I will buy some official ones.